# scrapy xpath how to use?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, selector

guys,
I have a question, scrapy, selector, XPath
I would like to choose the link in the "a" tag in the last "li" tag in HTML, and how to write the query for XPath
I did that, but I believe there are simpler ways to do that, such as using XPath queries, not using list fragmentation, but I don't know how to write

```
from scrapy import Selector

sel = Selector(text=html)
print sel.xpath('(//ul/li)').xpath('a/@href').extract()[-1]


'''
html
'''

</ul>
<li>
    <a href="/info/page/" rel="follow">
       <span class="page-numbers">
       35
       </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/info/page/" rel="follow">
        <span class="next">
        next page.
        </span>
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want specifically the link to the "next" page. If this is the case, you can locate an `a` element checking the child `span` to the "next" class:

```
//a[span/@class = "next"]/@href
```